# Broken titleps page style with clearpage and thispagestyle after a custom environment

Tags: environments, books, pagestyle, titleps, clearpage

The `titleps` style does not apply the last page style for section 1.3 before the `cleardoublepage` command (see the custom `\cleardoubletransition` command).

I think the bug is linked to `titleps` because if you apply a default style (e.g. `headings`), the page style at section 1.3 is correct.

Note that putting the `\cleardoubletransition` command in the `myenv` environment solve the issue.

How to make `titleps` page style robust with the custom environment, independently if you put a `\cleardoubletransition` at the end of the env. or outside it?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles,toctitles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}  % for \checkoddpage
\usepackage{lipsum}

% To clear double page and put transition
%
% USAGE
% \cleardoubletransition
%
\newcommand{\cleardoubletransition}%
{%
    \checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage\else \cleardoublepage\fi%
}

\newpagestyle{numchapnumsec}{%
    \sethead[
        {\sffamily\normalsize\thechapter\quad\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}
    ]
    []
    [
        {\sffamily\normalsize{\sectiontitle}\quad\thesection}
    ]
    {%
        {\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\quad{\sectiontitle}}
    }
    {}
    {%
        {\sffamily\normalsize\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}\quad\thechapter}
    }
    \setfoot*{}
    {%
        {\sffamily\thepage}
    }
    {}
}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
    \pagestyle{numchapnumsec} % It does not work properly
    % \pagestyle{headings} % It works properly
}{}

\begin{document}


\begin{myenv}
    \chapter{Chapter 1 title}

    \section{First section first chapter}

    \lipsum[1]
    \clearpage

    \section{All is ok here}

    \lipsum[2]
    \clearpage

    \section{Bug can appear for this page!}

    \lipsum[3]

    % \cleardoubletransition % with numchapnumsec, use this instead of the next one and it works!
\end{myenv}

\cleardoubletransition % Comment it if you use the previous cleardoubletransition cmd.

\begin{myenv}
    \chapter{Chapter 2 title}

    \section{First section new chapter}

    \lipsum[4]
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well sure. pagestyles are applied when the page is built, if you end your environment before the page break the style reverts. You could add a \newpage into the end of the environment.

Comment: In fact I finaly add a clearpage. I did not know the page must be complete for the pagestyle to be applied: I believed at least a sub part was sufficient. Thanks!